# Add and concat values tuple list .NET

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, tuples

I have following code:

```
var failed = new List<(IProductChecker<TModel> name, IDictionary<int, string[]> failedProducts)>();
foreach (var ids in batches)
{
   var batch = Check(names, ids.ToArray()); // List<(IProductChecker<TModel> checker, IDictionary<int, string[]> failedProducts)>()
   
   failed.AddRange(batch);
}
```

currently I am adding range, however as I iterate through batches, names can repeat with different failedProducts, so my intention would be to add those products to existing `name` of batch. Something like:

```
if (failed.Any(x => batch.Select(b => b.checker).Contains(x.checker)))
{ 
   // concat products to existing dictionary as such name exists
  // add to failed[name].failedProducts.Add(batch[name].failedProducts)
}
else
{  // add new failed if such name does not exists
   // failed.Add(...)
}
```

but I can't figure out how to do that. Maybe someone could give me a hint how to solve it?

Comment: Use FirstOrDefault with a predicate (condition) on the _failed_ list to find a tuple that matches the current batch. If found, add batch to dictionary of tuple...

Comment: `Any()` returns a `bool`, `Where` with `.ToList()` if you want the results.

Comment: What is the type of the `names` variable?